# Do not close bluetooth connection via CLI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I'm creating a bluetooth connection to my device, like so:

```
hcitool cc 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

That works fine for a few seconds, then the connection automatically closes. How do I keep linux from auto-closing the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to brush up on the hcitool flags.  My first guess would be that you are not completing the authentication but debug/verbose or logs are the best place to start looking.

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/hcitool1.html